# Avoid implicit conversion between float and integer for an array index

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

I am looking for a way to force the Fortran compiler to give an error message when I am using a real number in a situation where I should not.

For example,

```
Real :: i1,i2
Real :: A(1000,1000) , B(2000,2000)

A(i1:i2,:) =B(i1:i2,1:1000)
```

I had a code like this and I was not realizing my declarations of i1 and i2. 
Sometimes I used to get problems because of that until I realized it. Apparently, Fortran makes an implicit conversion, which I would rather be informed about.

Is there no way a Fortran compiler can see that the array is not being referenced with expected indices?

Comment: Read the documentation for the particular compiler you use.  All compilers I use or have used tend to have options that tell the compiler to be fairly strict in what it accepts.  For example, with gfortran you can do `gfortran -std=f2003` to get Fortran 2003 semantics, which will reject your program.  Without any options, gfortran simply issues a warning about an extension.

Comment: Fortran doesn't make an implicit conversion in this case.  In fact Fortran explicitly _disallows_ using real indexes here.  From your compiler tag, can we assume that you want to know how to have ifort complain?

Comment: Or use A(NINT(i1):NINT(i2)... it is somewhat odd that the compiler does not complain, but thee were a lot More gotchas in days gone by,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fortran language specification requires an array subscript to be a (scalar) integer expression.  Further, this is a part of the language that requires a valid Fortran compiler to be able to detect and report an attempt to violate this constraint.

Some compilers will choose to report this use of a real array index by default as an error.  Others may accept it as an extension and possibly providing a diagnostic warning.  The Intel compiler (currently) defaults to silently accepting this as an extension.  Even in those cases where a diagnostic isn't made, there should be an option to enable such reporting (for the compiler to be conforming to the Fortran specification).

In the case of ifort, the option `-stand`:

> warning #6187: Fortran 2008 requires an INTEGER data type in this context.

You can even combine this with `-diag-error=6187` to upgrade the diagnostic to an error.